# Sandboxing Chrome (or other browser)

Tags: security, sandbox

I'm wanting to run Chrome with an encrypted home directory (Ubuntu) but I want to make sure that nothing is leaking outside of the encrypted directory, such as /tmp. How might I accomplish this? Apparmour? Running a GUI app in docker? Preferably not a VM. How will I be able to verify it is working?

Comment: Ever tried `firejail` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mount /tmp as tmpfs, it will exist entirely in memory and will not touch the disk. This also has the benefit of decreasing latency and increasing speed or accesses. If you cannot do that, then yes, as you said, AppArmor or something similar is probably the best bet. It would also help protect you a bit more from a compromised browser as well.

A simple test to see if it worked is by putting `file:///tmp/` in the omnibar and seeing if it loads, then checking `dmesg` to see if AppArmor has denied access. If your distribution's AppArmor policy does not block access to /tmp by default, you can override that behavior by running the following:

```
# echo "deny /tmp/ w," >> /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.chrome
# echo "deny /tmp/** w," >> /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.chrome
```

And then restarting AppArmor (`/etc/init.d/apparmor reload`) and restarting the browser. Make sure the path is correct, and is in the `apparmor.d/local` path, or it will be overwritten on the next update. You may find these resources useful:

http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/QuickProfileLanguage

http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference